# Replace only replacing the 1st argument

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].replace(regex={'$': 1, '$$': 2, '$$$': 3})

df['Price'].fillna(0)
```

but even if a row had "$$" or "$$$" it still replaces it with a 1.0.

How can I make it appropriately replace $ with 1, $$ with 2, and $$$ with 3?

Comment: Can you provide an example of data? Do you only have `$` as value or also other characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df.Price.map({'$': 1, '$$': 2, '$$$': 3})
```

Comment: From my understanding , the price can not only be the dollar sign .. so you will end up get all NaN

Comment: Ya, you can fillna 0 just like the one in the quesion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really want to use regex matching and not a simple `map`, you need to fix 2 things.

1- escape `$` which means *end of string* in regex

2- put the patterns in reverse order of length in the dictionary to have $$$ be evaluated before $$ and before $ (`{r'\$\$\$': 3, r'\$\$': 2, r'\$': 1}`)

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': ['abc $', 'def $$', '$$$']})
df['new'] = df['price'].replace(regex={r'\$\$\$': 3, r'\$\$': 2, r'\$': 1})
```

Output:

```
    price  new
0   abc $    1
1  def $$    2
2     $$$    3
```